# How to get form data in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I need get data from form.

I use JavaScript to create form:

```
<script>   
function checkAuth() {
                var user = ADAL.getCachedUser();
                if (user) {
                    var form = $('<form style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; opacity: 0; display: none; visibility: hidden;" method="POST" action= "{{ url_for("general.microsoft") }}">');

                    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + ADAL.getCachedToken(ADAL.config.clientId) + '">');
                    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="json" value="' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(user)) + '">');
                    $("body").append(form);
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
</script>
```

then I need to get data from the input field which `name="json"`.

Here is my view function:

```
@general.route("/microsoft/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@csrf.exempt
def microsoft():
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    name = form['json'].value
    return name
```

But I get an error:

`builtins.KeyError KeyError: 'json'`

Help me get data from form.

Comment: can you provide more detail please?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint script transmits data to the Python where they are processed. I need to pull value data from the `name="json"`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can get form data from Flask's request object with the `form` attribute:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    data = request.form['input_name']  # pass the form field name as key
    ...
```

You can also set a default value to avoid 400 errors with the `get()` method since the `request.form` attribute is a dict-like object:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    default_value = '0'
    data = request.form.get('input_name', default_value)
    ...
```

P.S. You may also want to check out [Flask-WTF](https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf) for form validation and form HTML rendering.

Comment: Thanks and how I can decode `name`? Because return answer `eb2a-4390-8283-1be75d3ad422%22%2C%22oid%22%3A%22a3c6887f-614b-42b7-9a08-`

Comment: That's a new question... You may need to accept my answer and write another question :)

Comment: How do you use this with the `render_template`?