# Upload an image to make a post from file in Python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to upload an image to then evaluate a machine learning model but the post I receive is empty.

## My code

```
#Basic libraries
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

#Image libraries
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from skimage import color


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class MakePrediction(Resource):
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        orig_img = request.get_json()
        
        #Here I have to read the image from post or save the image also
        #orig_img=mpimg.imread(orig_img.file)
       
        
        print(orig_img)
        return orig_img
    
api.add_resource(MakePrediction, '/predict')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='8050')
```

When I try to do a post from postman for example what I am getting is `null`. Is there a way to make a post, get the file and then process it?

[image]

Comment: See if this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154602/how-to-get-form-data-in-flask) is helpful

Comment: @Sociopath Yes, but how raise the server on my local? I'm new on this